# VR view 360 photo sphere images, possible CORS issue

Tags: javascript, cors, photo, 360-panorama

I am trying to create a page to show 360 photos I took with my Nexus 6 default camera app in panoramic mode.

Using the Google documentation, I created a local website "video360.dev"

```
<div id="vrview"></div>
```

remote hosted libraries seemed to get me further

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>
```

I tried, locally hosted image, image on my domain and an image hosting solution:

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
        function onVrViewLoad() {
          var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {

            //Taken with nexus6 default camera app in panoramic mode
            image: 'http://www.darrencousins.com/images/1.jpg',
            // image: '1.jpg',
            // image: 'https://image.ibb.co/jCpmGQ/1.jpg',

            // video: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/304756/rabbit360_HD_1280x640_low.mp4',

            is_stereo: true,
            width:'100%',
            height:'800px'
          });
        }
    </script>
```

To make sure I wasn't going mad, I "borrowed" a working video line from an existing codepen, it worked fine, it's just something about my image or hosting setup.

I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/sygad1/pen/ZKGKEG) to try and remove the whole "local hosting" issue as I believe I have a CORS issue, but unsure how to solve it.

[image: issue seen when locally hosting]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code’s sending a request for https://image.ibb.co/jCpmGQ/1.jpg using XHR and your browser is getting the response—but the response lacks the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, so your browser isn’t allowing your frontend JavaScript code to actually access the response. That’s what browsers do for cross-origin requests when there’s no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in the response. That’s how CORS works.

Therefore probably your only option is to send the request through a CORS proxy instead.

So what you can try is, where you’re specifying the URL `https://image.ibb.co/jCpmGQ/1.jpg` in your code now, just replace that with this URL:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://image.ibb.co/jCpmGQ/1.jpg
```

That will cause the request to be sent to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` instead, which is a CORS proxy. That proxy will then send the request for `https://image.ibb.co/jCpmGQ/1.jpg` and when it gets the response, the proxy will take it and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to it and then pass that back to your requesting frontend code as the response.

That response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what your browser sees, so the error message the browser is showing you now goes away, and the browser allows your frontend JavaScript code to access the response.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for that. I also temporarily got around the issue by installing a chrome extension to enable CORS, not an ideal solution but at least it confirmed my suspicions.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work locally? I use MAMP Pro as my server

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere is whats used by that heroku server, might be useful if someone wants to host their own

Comment: @user2312688 Thanks yeah I put some more details in the **How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141

Comment: Thanks for the answer... till yesterday it was working, from today not working!! is there any logical reason?

Comment: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com is designed for temporary projects and debugging, it's not for production projects. Indeed they ended recently free support and they added limitations to usage.